# Class method wraps a function - Problems with Arguments

Tags: python, class, error-handling, try-catch

In my main, I have a function with an error and a class that tracks errors in a list inside the class itself. In other words, instead of just calling the function, I would like to give this function to a class-method which then "logs" the error in a list and suppresses the error.

Here is my problem:
This function has input arguments. When I hand-over my function to the class-method, I would like to hand-over the inputs, too. What happens is, that the function is being executed ***before*** going to the class method. Therefore, the class-method can't suppress the error which happens in the function.

In the code below, I set the variable `silent=True`, therefore, it should not raise an error (because of the try/except clause within the method). Unfortunately, the code raises a TypeError which comes from the function.

Any advice would be much appreciated

PS: I am not looking for a decorator solution :)

Here is the **class** with the class method which can suppress the error

```
class ErrorTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list()

    def track_func(self, func, silent=False):
        try:
            self.list.append('...in trying')
            print('....trying.....')
            return func
        except Exception as e:
            self.list.append('...in except')
            self.list.append(e)  # important line - here the error gets "logged"
            if not silent:
                raise e
```

Here is the **function with an error**

```
def transformation_with_error(app1, app2):
    # DO STUFF HERE with inputs
    result = str(app1)+str(app2)
    print(result)
    print('TYPE ERROR here')
    raise TypeError
    return result
```

Here the **main routine**:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    error_tracker = ErrorTracker()

    print('-- start transformation')
    error_tracker.track_func(transformation_with_error(app1='AA', app2='BB'), silent=True)
    print('-- end transformation')

    print(error_tracker.list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue, in your main routine

```
error_tracker.track_func(transformation_with_error(app1='AA', app2='BB'), silent=True)
```

calls `transformation_with_error` before entering `error_tracker.track_func`. This happens just because you indeed are calling `transformation_with_error`. If you want your `error_tracker.track_func` to call `transformation_with_error`, you have to pass the later as an argument, like you would do for a callback.

For example:

```
def test(var1, var2):
    print("{} {}".format(var1, var2))

def callFn(func, *vars):
    func(*vars)

callFn(test, "foo", "bar")
```

outputs `foo bar`

Answer (score 0):

Thx VincentRG
That was it
Just for the record, below are the changes I did:
(side note: I added the **kwargs, too, to be able to deal with default values)

thx mate

**class changes**

```
class ErrorTracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = list()

    def track_func(self, func, silent=False, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.list.append('...in trying')
            print('....trying.....')
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            self.list.append('...in except')
            self.list.append(e)   # important line - here the error gets "logged"
            if not silent:
                raise e
```

**change in call**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    error_tracker = ErrorTracker()

    print('-- start transformation')
    error_tracker.track_func(transformation_with_error, silent=True, app1='AA', app2='BB')
    print('-- end transformation')

    print(error_tracker.list)
```